# Using dplyr and table function

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(raster)
my.shp <- getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=1)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID_1 = rep(my.shp$ID_1, each = 100), 
                 category = sample(c("early", "medium", "late"), 22 * 100, replace = T))
```

I want to convert `df` into a `df1` which looks like this:

```
ID_1   length.of.early. length.of.medium length.of.late
```

i.e. for each ID_1, I want to create the number of entries of early, medium and late and then add it to the `my.shp`

```
df %>% group_by(ID_1) %>% table(category) # how do I apply the 'table' function here
```

I will then join `df1` to `my.shp` using this:

```
dat.shp <- merge(my.shp, df1, by = "ID_1")
```

and then plot `dat.shp` as a map and show `length.of.early`, `length.of.medium` and `length.of.late` as barplots for each `ID_1` on the map. I found this post that could help me do it

https://nzprimarysectortrade.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/let-r-fly-visualizing-export-data-using-r/

but in order to do this, I have to first create the `df1`. Note that I can write a loop to do this but I am looking for a dplyr solution to this or any other solution that avoids a loop.

Comment: Do you need `df %>% count(ID_1, category) %>% spread(category, n)` or use `table(df)`

Comment: Oh. Both of them give the same result. Thanks. I actually had multiple columns in my `df` and hence whenever I did `table(df)` it gave me strnage results. Now I am going to filter the `ID_1` and `category` in the original data and then use `table(df)` as suggested. Thanks

Comment: If there are multiple columns, just subset the columns and use `table` i.e. `table(df[c('ID_1', 'category')])`